# Check stream connection status grpc

Tags: c#, grpc

I am streaming from server to client. In my stream method i only wait in while until i use CancellationToken. But i want use it when client lost connection and stream will interrupted. Have grpc method to check status?

```
   public override async Task Get(Compute compute, IServerStreamWriter<T> asyncStreamWriter, ServerCallContext ctx)
   {
        Computers.Set(compute, asyncStreamWriter);

        while (!ctx.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the RPC fails (client cancels, the connections is lost etc.), the gRPC server will automatically cancel the cancellation token. Please not that gRPC doesn't actively look for lost connectivity unless you're actually sending some data or you've setup keepalive channel options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know, i dont use SSL should it work to?